# How to put noone image in image column of datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I have to put an image to specific column of datagridview but not in every row.

```
If getExists(myTable, CInt(reader.GetValue(0)), dbConn) Then
  .Cells("myCol").Value = Image.FromFile("C:\myPath\myIco_16x16.ico")
Else
  .Cells("myCol").Value = "" ' error here
End If
```

With this code I get error while executing probably because I'm try to put a string in image column. Second I try is:

```
.Cells("myCol").Value = Nothing
```

This don't cause error but put "error image" picture (with red X) to grid.

Is here a way to put no one image (blank) to datagridview's image column without loading a "blank image" from file or resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had to do this in the past and just used a 1 pixel transparent PNG.  The performance was acceptable in my application even with 18 image columns and ~2000 rows and the background color of the cell shows through it just fine.

You should be able to create a 1x1 pixel transparent PNG fairly easily using a free program such as "Paint.Net".

Comment: Ok, if this is solution than creating an image would not be a problem. It is interesting that VB.NET creators didn't provide place without image in image column :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a temporary blank bitmap and assign this to rather than loading an image from file.

```
Friend Function BlankImage() As Image
    Try
        Dim oBM As New Bitmap(1, 1)
        oBM.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.Transparent)
        Return oBM
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: Please give us an example on how to use this function.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly better method that can improve performance:

```
Friend Function BlankImage() As Image
    Static oBM As New Bitmap(1, 1)
    Try

        If oBM Is Nothing Then
            oBM.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.Transparent)
        End If
        Return oBM
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try

End Function
```